# openpyxl draw date x-scale

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i want to use openpyxl to draw a chart on excel,but i dont know how to use this date time to  be the x axis

```
    print(foPath,sheetName)
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from openpyxl.chart import (
    LineChart,
    Reference,Series
    )
    from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis
    wb = load_workbook(filename=foPath)
    sheetsName = wb.sheetnames

    # print(foPath) 
    sheet1 = wb[sheetsName[0]]
    print(sheet1['P3'].value)
    ws = wb.active
    c2 = LineChart()
    xvalues = Reference(ws,min_col=16,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
    xxvalue = Reference(ws,min_col=17,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
    sxvalue = Reference(ws,min_col=18,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
    s1value = Reference(ws,min_col=19,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
    s2value = Reference(ws,min_col=20,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
    s3value = Reference(ws,min_col=21,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
    s4value = Reference(ws,min_col=22,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
    s5value = Reference(ws,min_col=23,min_row=2,max_row=10000)

    c2.x_axis = DateAxis(crossAx=100)
    c2.x_axis.number_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    
    c2.set_categories(xvalues)
    
    # c2.x_axis = axis.DateAxis()
    # c2.x_axis.number_format = "yyyy/mm/dd"
    c2.add_data(xxvalue,titles_from_data=True)
    c2.add_data(sxvalue,titles_from_data=True)
    c2.add_data(s1value,titles_from_data=True)
    c2.add_data(s2value,titles_from_data=True)
    c2.add_data(s3value,titles_from_data=True)
    c2.add_data(s4value,titles_from_data=True)
    c2.add_data(s5value,titles_from_data=True)
    ws.add_chart(c2,'A1')
    wb.save(foPath)
```

inside the code the xvalue is what i wanto be the x axis ,its time  data,other data is for y axis ,.
these code makes no x axis for date but 1 to 100000,and it also cause some problems ,

if i didnt set c2.x_axis
these code makes no x axis for date but 1 to 100000,
but if i set it
and it also cause some problems ,
how can i fix it
pretty thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

```
xvalues = Reference(ws,min_col=16,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
xxvalue = Reference(ws,min_col=17,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
sxvalue = Reference(ws,min_col=18,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
s1value = Reference(ws,min_col=19,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
s2value = Reference(ws,min_col=20,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
s3value = Reference(ws,min_col=21,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
s4value = Reference(ws,min_col=22,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
s5value = Reference(ws,min_col=23,min_row=2,max_row=10000)
```

this data rows` title are from the row2, so if i need to get the xvalue to be the x axis. i need to ignore the title from row2, so i need to use

```
xvalues = Reference(ws,min_col=16,min_row=3,max_row=10000)
```

it will start from the data instead of title.
thats all .

Comment: Or simply not pass set `titles_from_data=True`